# Asset validation Error while validating app in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, app-store-connect

I have filled all the image slots in Xcode ad still I am still getting this error while validating my app to submit it to App Store. Can anyone please help?

```
Asset validation failed
Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod 
Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 10.0. To 
support. older versions of iOS, the icon may be required in the bundle outside of an 
asset catalog. Make sure the Info.plist file includes appropriate entries referencing 
the file. For details, see https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface- 
guidelines/icons-and-images/app-icon/. (ID: 4755ba7d-b601-4bf1-85f0-26f0923fd831)

Asset validation failed
Missing App Icon. An app icon measuring 1024 by 1024 pixels in PNG format must be 
included in the Asset Catalog of apps built for iOS, iPadOS, or watchOS. Without this 
icon, apps cannot be submitted for review. For details, see 
https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/app- 
icon/. (ID: 6110edbf-73e0-43c2-89ab-b0e920090b1b)
```

Comment: Delete the `AppIcon` file and recreate it, Apple adds new requirements once in a while. The new version will have the new requirements.

Comment: Did it still get the same error. Its been 3 days...have tried almost everything....cznt figure it out.

Comment: Are you using the latest Xcode

Comment: yes, XCode 14.3.1

Comment: There is a newer one in the store. Try recreating the AppIcon after you get the new one.

Comment: Updated to Xcode 15. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Something else is going on then, do you have multiple AppIcon files? Maybe for different targets? Check all over your target. You you have any triangle warning symbols in the AppIcon file

Comment: Updated to Xcode 15 but still same error.

Comment: Just to be sure - the images you're trying to use are .png, right? It might help to remove transparency from them too.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check your target configuration, to make sure the correct icon is named and also included:

[image: AppIcon]

You might also want to check that the asset catalog is included in the bundled resources. Select the file in the Navigator and look in the File inspector (on the right hand side of the XCode window) to check that target membership is included. Or just check the listing under Target > Build Phases > Copy Bundled Resources:
[image: BundledResources]

Comment: I already had the same settings. Still followed the steps by deleting files in Build phases and again adding assets and preview assets. But still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Just posting in case it helps someone because I wasted a week figuring it out. I suggest fill all the slots in the assets.xcassets and what i was doing wrong is that I had my Asset folder inside a folder (I had putassets and preview assets inside a folder). Instead Assets should be inside your root app. When I moved it outside the folder, app got validated. Hope it helps.